# .NET sdk issue without any anwsers

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli

[image: The error message]

I am trying to use the command "dotnet new console" and follow a brackeys tutorial.

I have the following installed.

[image: The ones I have installed]

Comment: Run both `dotnet --list-runtimes` and `dotnet --list-sdks`. Post your results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question will probably be downvoted and possibly closed due to including screenshots instead of writing error as text/code snippet. Have a look at the Stack Overflow best practices for questions.
Regarding your question: dotnet is most likely not part of the Windows $PATH variable.

Comment: @gunr2171 
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.16 [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

the dotnet --list-sdks doesnt return anything

Comment: @citronas how do i fix that?

Comment: Try downloading and installing sdk from the [site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) again (_"Download .NET SDK x64"_ option.). Maybe reboot your machine.

Comment: try this in your F:\Program path dotnet new globaljson and let me know if it helps